# Code refactoring a long JavaScript string so its easier to style

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I am wondering if there is a better way to write this JavaScript (Jquery) code.
This snippet dynamically created a H3 with a link.

My designer is going nuts trying to style this as its in JavaScript.
I am trying to re-write / refactor this into to smaller chunks to allow my designer to style without looking at all this code on one single line.

```
var dvClassContainer = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'dvclassconatiner_' + classVal).attr("classifname", classifname).attr("memclassnumber", memclassnumber).html('<h3>' + classifname + '<a id="ancclassremove_'+ classVal +'" classVal="' + classVal + '" onclick="RemoveClassificationUponConfirm(\'' + classVal + '\');" class="buttons delete btnSmall">Delete</a></h3><img style="display:none;" id="imgloadRemClass_' + classVal + '" alt="loading" src="../Images/application/smallUploading.gif" />');
```

I was thinking of creating more variables and combining them together.
Is there a 'cleaner' way of writing this?

Comment: At some point you or somebody else should have a long, serious talk with whomever wrote that code.

Comment: This is also true; `$(document.createElement('div'))` is a work of art

Comment: We used a sub-contractor - we are realizing how bad this code is as we are now maintaining it.

Comment: So you need a solution without the designer looking at JS?

Comment: Throw away this code and start over again. Throw away all code written by the same person and rewrite it. Fire him and don't pay him. Adopt a "non-horizontality" policy of disallowing any code longer than 80 characters on a line; JSLint supports this. Consider an alternative to jQuery for building DOM structures, including templating, or libraries which allow you to build them with nested function calls such as `div({id:div_id},[children...])`.

Comment: @torazaburo - We are rewriting the code from scratch. The out-sourced programmer is no longer going to be used. -- Looks like I am working all weekend again.

Comment: Good move--thanks for the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you utilize more of jQuery's features, the code becomes more readable and more easily maintained:

```
var dvClassContainer = $('<div>');
dvClassContainer.attr({
  id: 'dvclasscontainer_'+classVal,
  classifname: classifname,
  memclassnumber: memclassnumber
});
var dvHeader = $('<h3>');
var dvHeaderLink = $('<a>Delete</a>');
dvHeaderLink.attr({
  id: 'ancclassremove_'+classVal,
  classVal: 'classVal',
  class: 'buttons delete btnSmall'
}).on('click',function(){
  RemoveClassificationUponConfirm(classVal);
});
var dvImg = $('<img>');
dvImg.attr({
  id: 'imgloadRemClass_'+classVal,
  alt: 'loading',
  src: '../Images/application/smallUploading.gif'
});
dvClassContainer.append(dvHeader.append(dvHeaderLink.append(dvImg)));
```

Ideally, you would also want to move all those non-standard attributes (classifname, memclassnumber, classVal) to `data-` attributes, which would be accessible via jQuery's `data()` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
var dvClassContainer = $(document.createElement('div'))
                            .attr("id", 'dvclassconatiner_' + classVal)
                            .attr("classifname", classifname)
                            .attr("memclassnumber", memclassnumber)
                            .html('<h3>' + classifname + '<a id="ancclassremove_'+ classVal +'" classVal="' + classVal + '" onclick="RemoveClassificationUponConfirm(\'' + classVal + '\');" class="buttons delete btnSmall">Delete</a></h3><img style="display:none;" id="imgloadRemClass_' + classVal + '" alt="loading" src="../Images/application/smallUploading.gif" />');
```

The last line still needs fixing. I would create elements and then set their attributes and then append them to the `h3`. You can do that using `var h3 = $("<h3></h3>");` (as an example) and set attributes using `.attr()` and finally `.append()` to put it all together.

Comment: You solution is easiest to read, however, combining the ATTR as jackwanders did seems to be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go a different way with this, after acknowledging that this one line of code is nasty.

It's not the JavaScript that's giving your designer headaches. If they can't style this with CSS, they're not trying hard enough. Surely that h3 and anchor are inside other elements that they can grab for some styling:

```
.someContainer h3 { color: chartreuse; }
```

However, if they HAVE tried everything possible, you still just need to add a new class or two (to the h3 and the anchor). Where you have `.html('<h3>'...` you would change it to `.html('<h3 class="someClass">'...`

As much as we have fun optimizing and downright fixing bad JS in poor implementations, if we assume that this is "working", the problem is the designer's ability to style. This is therefore not really a JavaScript issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dvClassContainer = $('<div/>')
     .attr({'id': 'dvclassconatiner_' + classVal,
           'classifname': classifname,
           'memclassnumber': memclassnumber
     })
     .html(
         function() {
             var $title = $('<h3>' + classifname + '</h3>');
             var $link = $('<a>Delete</a>').attr({
                 'id': 'ancclassremove_' + classVal,
                 'classVal': classVal,
                 'class': 'buttons delete btnSmall'
             })
             .on('click', function() {
                 RemoveClassificationUponConfirm(classVal);
             });

             var $img = $('<img/>').attr({
                 'id': 'imgloadRemClass_' + classVal,
                 'alt': 'loading',
                 'src': '../Images/application/smallUploading.gif'
             })
             .css('display', 'none');

             return $title.append($link).add($img);
     });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3zWzT/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Douglas Crockford's Supplant method. It tokenizes a string so you can dynamically build strings out. Here is a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/mmeah/F23rk/

```
// http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html
if (!String.prototype.supplant) {
    String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
        return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
            function (a, b) {
                var r = o[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}

var classVal="x", classifname="y", memclassnumber="z"; //predefined

var dvClassHtml = $("#someDiv").html();
$("#someDiv").html("");
var params ={
    "classVal":classVal,
    "classifname":classifname,
    "memclassnumber":memclassnumber
};
dvClassHtml=dvClassHtml.supplant(params);

var dvClassContainer = 
$(document.createElement('div'))
.attr("id", 'dvclassconatiner_' + classVal)
.attr("classifname", classifname)
.attr("memclassnumber", memclassnumber)
.html(dvClassHtml);
```

Comment: Douglas Crockford giving a presentation on Supplant: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2ifWcnQs6M#t=1h14m16s

Comment: Oops var params is a reserved word. Use another variable name instead of "params"